# I can't pass a return value from a function to another and get "use of udeclared identifier

Tags: c, function, scope, return, cs50

I can't get my head around this problem, I'm doing the CS50 class on edX and try to solve the Week 2 task, being my first time doing some C coding.
I write this script to return the number of letters in a given input by user, but it seems that the functions are not connecting to each others.

What I'm trying to do here its get an input text from `getText` function and pass the return value to `validChars` function and two more funtions that I did not write yet. Then get the return values from `validChars` `sentences` and `wholeText` functions to the main function to perform a Math problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string getText(string text);
int validChars(int vch);

int main(void)
{
    int mainchars = validChars(vc);
    printf("Letras : %i", mainchars);
    printf("\n");
}

string getText(string ctext)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    return text;
}

int validChars(int vch)
{
    string text = getText(text);
    int vc;
    int n;
    n = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
        {
            vc++;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            vc++;
        }
    }
    return vc;
}
```

I get the **error: use of undeclared identifier 'vc'** on line 11. I been stuck on this for the last hours today trying to solve it myself but without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int mainchars = validChars(vc);`. Well, where is `vc` declared in `main`? That is, where do you expect `main` to get the `vc` variable from?

Comment: Another problem: `int vc; .. vc++` . That results in undefined behaviour because `vc` is unintialised. Do `int vc = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `vc` as an argument when you call `validChars`, but you never declared this variable, so you get an error due to using an undeclared variable. The variable is local to the `validChars` function, but that doesn't make it available in `main`.

There's no need for that to be a parameter to the function, it never uses the parameter. The function should take `text` as a parameter, and you should call `getText()` in `main()`.

You shouldn't test character ranges, use the built-in `isalpha()` function.

You need to initialize `vc` to `0` before you can use it as a counter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string getText(string text);
int validChars(void);

int main(void)
{
    string text = getText(text);
    int mainchars = validChars(vc);
    printf("Letras : %i", mainchars);
    printf("\n");
}

string getText(string ctext)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    return text;
}

int validChars(string text)
{
    int vc = 0;
    int n = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            vc++;
        }
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Comment: we do not know if the have learned isalpha and similar functions (it is a very beginning of course), They need also to learn how to do it without using other functions. IMO even `strlen` should be written by them at this stage to learn C strings.

Comment: @P__J__ They have `#include <ctype.h>`, so it seems like they were expected to use those functions.

Comment: My bad, this is Week 2 of the course, but it's my first time doing C. What I'm trying to do its setting up a function to get a string input by user, then that function should return the entire string and be use in 3 diferents functions.
```validChars```
```Sentences```
```wholetext```
Then, these 3 functions should return those values to the main function to do a math test.
So, as you can see, I'm stuck at the very beggining. 
It seems to me that I don-t know how to call functions and recieve parameters from them. I should look more into it.

Comment: What PJ states its correct. We just see the the strlen function in this week. I guess its not a problem if I solve this by using the isalpha function but the class didn't actually cover it yet.
Also, i include ctype.h but I did not use it on the script

Answer (score 0):

1. You call the function with parameter `vc`. `vc` is not defined in main or in the global scope.
2. Parameter `vch` is not needed as you do not pass any information from the called to the function.

Amended code:

```
int validChars(void);

int main(void)
{
    int mainchars = validChars();
    printf("Letras : %i", mainchars);
    printf("\n");
}

string getText(string ctext)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    return text;
}

int validChars()
{
    string text = getText(text);
    int vc=0;
    int n;
    n = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
        {
            vc++;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            vc++;
        }
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Comment: Hello PJ, thanks for answering to my problem. I'm trying to get the return value from validChars funtion to main, not the other way around

Comment: @jpmer `return` statement returns value to the calling function

Answer (score 0):

I could not readily find your CS50 problem set.

The compiler error you are receiving is telling you the variable vc has not yet been declared (defined) before trying to use it. The computer starts executing the lines of code within main() and hasn't been told what value vc represents.

```
int main(void)
{
int mainchars = validChars(vc);
printf("Letras : %i", mainchars);
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hello. I misspelled, It's week 2 of CS50 class. The name of the assingment its readability.
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/#:~:text=ior%20of%20the%20resulting%20program